# Loss functions in Convolutional neural networks

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am implementing a convolutional neural network and I cannot seem to grasp how the loss function affects the implementation.

So far I have the basic layers like convolutional, pooling etc. I also have the dense (fully connected layer, no hidden layers there) that has no activation function, because I implemented activation function as a separate layer that is put after the fully connected layer, but can also be put after the convolutional layer. I have seen that in some implementations.

The activation layer simply computes an activation function (e.g. sigmoid, relu, softmax etc.) during forward propagation and during backward propagation the gradients coming in are just multiplied by the derivative of output and passed on.

Example for sigmoid activation layer:

```
Forward propagation = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-input)
Backward propagation = outputValue * (1 - outputValue) * inputGradient
```

I think that is correct so far. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Since I am using Mean Squared Error, at the end I simply compute the difference between each output and expected output (outputVector[i] - expectedVector[i]) and pass it to backpropagation as gradient. Than it first goes via the activation layer which modifies it and passes it to fully connected. So it works as a normal neural network with no hidden layer that has activation functions applied directly.

Now I would like to implement more loss functions - Cross Entropy to be precise. I have looked at some codes of simple neural networks with no hidden layers that have activation functions computed directly, that they pass the gradient as

```
(outputValue - expectedValue)
```

In Mean Squared Error they pass it as

```
(outputValue - expectedValue) * derivativeOfActivationFuction(outputValue )
```

Since I have the activation layer separate (as I have seen in other implementations) I cannot figure what to pass in as a gradient from outside as it gets multiplied by the derivative of activation function. I could of course use a reverse operation or pass a flag to the last activation layer that says the multiplication should not happen. But this just does not seem universal or correct.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it wrong that I implemented the activation function as separate layer? Or is there just something I am missing and I just need to change the way I compute gradients that are passed to the very last layer?

Answer (score 2):

Let me get this straight. You're writing a convolutional layer and the gradient propagation from scratch? Bravo! I commend your unnecessary struggles.

With that said, the gradients are effectively just a long version of the chain rule. So for your example of Mean Squared Error, we can write the function for MSE of your output as MSE(F(w)), where F is the network leading up to that point, and w is your 'weight' (let's assume you just have one to make things easier).

What we want is the derivative of MSE with respect to w, so d/dw(MSE(F(w)). By the chain rule, this is MSE'(F(w)) * F'(w). The definition for MSE is ((F(w) - y)^2)/2. The derivative of this with respect to w is (F(w) - y). So plug that in and you get what you wrote out: (F(w) - y) * F'(w).

What you want, now, is to do the cross entropy rather than the mean squared error. That's totally fine to do, but will take on a different form. Instead of MSE(F(w)), you'll have CE(F(w)), where CE = cross_entropy. The gradient will be similarly different, where it'll be CE'(F(w)) * F'(w) rather than MSE'(F(w)) * F'(w). The F'(w) is the same, but now you have the derivative of cross entropy multiplying by it.

So whatever your activation function is, you need to multiply the F'(w) by the activation function's derivative in order to get your complete gradient. Hopefully that clears it up. I can't be more helpful in specifics, since I don't see your code and, as such, have no idea how you're actually implementing anything.